# Porque mi boton logout no es reactivo?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

tengo en vuejs un componente Nav, para la barra de navegacion del top, este es el componente:

```
<template>
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
      <button  id="btn_logout"  v-if="isAuth" @click="logout" to="/logout">Cerrar Sesión</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex';
export default {
  name: 'Nav',
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['logout'])
  },
  computed:{
   ...mapGetters(['isAuth'])
  }
 
}
</script>
```

El tema es que quiero que el boton de cerrar sesion  salga solo cuando tengo en el localstorage el token **auth** , cuando le doy a logout me elimina el localstorage bien y todo, pero no es ractivo, es decir, tengo que refrescar la pagina para que checkee que ya no esta, en lugar de hacerlo automaticamente.

Para hacer todo esto, si os fijais tengo dos funciones : **logout** y **isAuth** . Forman parte de mi store (vuex) :

Mi store.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import router from '@/router/index'

export default createStore({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
    logout(state){
      console.log('store - logout')
      localStorage.clear('auth');
      router.push('/login');
    
    },
    setAuth(state,authToken){
      console.log('im store !!');
      localStorage.setItem('auth',authToken);
    },
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  },
  getters:{
    isAuth(){
      return localStorage.getItem('auth');
    }
  }
})
```

Estoy con el debugger de vuejs. Y cada vez que hago logout el token de localstorage parece que desaparece bien. Pero esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que deberia de estar  siendo reactivo, y mostrarse segun devuelve tru o false el getter de mi vuex (que checkea el localstorage) no lo esta siendo. Solo funciona al recargar la pagina que es cuando lo lee de nuevo.

El sistema de logeo es el siguiente:

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <form 
    id="login"
    @submit.prevent="login"
    method="post"
    >
        <input type="text" v-model="user.name">
        <br>
        <input type="password" v-model="user.password">
        <br>
        <button>Iniciar Sesion</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>import axios from "axios";
import { RouterLink } from "vue-router";
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  props: {
  
  },
  data() {
    return {
      user:{
        name:'',
        password:''
      }
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log('store');
    console.log(this.$store);
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['setAuth']),
    login(){

        let authToken = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999999 - 1000000)) + 1000000;
        this.setAuth(authToken);
        this.$router.push('/home')

        // axios.post('/login', this.user)
        //          .then((res) => {
        //              //Perform Success Action
        //          })
        //          .catch((error) => {
        //              // error.response.status Check status code
        //          }).finally(() => {
        //              //Perform action in always
        //          });
    }
  },
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que solo estas utilizando el localStorage y no almacenas nada en tu store con vuex, para que te funcione deberías guardar el valor de isAuth en el state de vuex y consultar su valor con una computed

```
     state()=>{
         isAuth: false,
     },
     setAuth(state,authToken) {
          console.log('im store !!');
          state.isAuth = !state.isAuth
          localStorage.setItem('auth',authToken);
     },
     logout(state){
          console.log('store - logout')
          localStorage.clear('auth');
          state.isAuth = !state.isAuth
          router.push('/login');
      },
```

para obtener el valor de isAuth no es necesario hacerlo desde un getter debido a que no haces ningun tipo de transformación, filtro, o formato en tu respuesta lo puedes hacer directamente desde el state ya sea con `this.$store.state.isAuth` o con un helper de vuex.

```
computed: {
    isAuth() {
        return this.$store.state.isAuth
     }
    
}
```

Tambien existen paquetes que te ayudan a todo esto como [vuepersiste](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist)